# Windows Server 2016 : DNS policies

Tags: dns, windows-server-2016

I have 2 VLANs : 10.0.0.0/24 and 10.1.0.0/24.

The address of the host "www.domain.fr" has to be different depending the subnet, but the address of "mail.domain.fr" has to be the same, regardless the subnet.

So I setup new "DnsServerClientSubnet", new "DnsServerZoneScope", new "DnsServerResourceRecord" and to finish, new "DnsServerQueryResolutionPolicy".
The host "mail.domain.fr" is set in the GUI (the default zone).

The resolution of host "www.domain.fr" is different regarding the subnet, it's OK for me. But the resolution of "mail.domain.fr" is not effective.

So my question is : Must I create the "mail" reccord in every subnet, even if the reccord is the same ? Or is there way to make a policy that when a host is not found in a scope, make the search in the default zone ?

Thanks

Nicolas